# PHP получить url ajax запроса, без явного указания

Tags: php, ajax

Я передаю данные в php, с помощью ajax(post), подскажите как я могу узнать url страницы отправления, без явного указания url?

Comment: Посмотреть на заголовок Referer, но его может не быть или он может быть неполным. Или вообще поддельным

Comment: Вот, я именно про то, что его легче всего подделать, возможно существует другой способ?

Comment: Другого способа не существует. Любой из них можно будет подделать

Comment: @ArchDemon, хорошо

Comment: А если передавать какой-нибудь зашифрованный параметр

Comment: Что мешает этот параметр получить и продублировать в других обращениях к серверу?

Comment: Может лучше расскажете какую задачу вы хотите решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писал решение на основе хэш-сумм, однако, в процессе понял, что ваша проблема в том, что она описана в разрезе того, что мы не можем никак доверять клиенту и определить, что запрос был отправлен именно с нашего клиента и данные в нем достоверны.

Могу предположить, что с аутентификацией клиента имеются определенные проблемы, стоит посмотреть в эту сторону. Например, [система аутентификации на основе JWT](https://habr.com/ru/post/340146/) довольно неплохо может помочь обезопасить клиент-серверное общение.

Если добиться должной безопасности при верификации клиента, то можно организовать следующее поведение:

1. Первый запрос содержит url в явном виде и получает в ответ hash-сумму созданную из url (желательно с солью, подробнее [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F))).
2. Второй запрос содержит данные + hash-сумма из первого запроса.
3. На данном этапе, сервер берет значение `referrer_url` и прогоняет его через тот же алгоритм hash-ирования и сверяет полученную сумму с той, которую получили в запросе. Если суммы равны, то мы можем быть уверены в достоверности значения `referrer_url`.

При реализации описанного поведения, становится очень сложным подделать hash-сумму отправленную в основном запросе, даже если определить алгоритм hash-ирования, то камнем преткновения выступит рандомная соль, которую вы примешаете.

**Один из немногих способов подделать hash-сумму в целевом запросе, это иметь возможность отправить полноценный подделанный первый запрос, который пройдет верификацию на сервере и вернет рассчитанную сумму для неверного url-a, но это возможно, только при слабой аутентификации клиента.**

*Если вам будет недостаточно приведенной теоретической информации, пожалуйста, опишите минимальную инфраструктуру, аутентификацию и причину, по которой вы считаете, не нужно использовать url в запросе, в явном виде.*

Comment: @artemgh Если я угадал и проблема лежит в слабой аутентификации/верификации и определении целевого клиента, то советую открыть новый вопрос на соответствующую тему (постараюсь вам помочь).